# Find the matrix $A$ representing rotation around the direction $(1, 1, 1)$ by $\pi/2$ radians counter-clockwise

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider the linear transformation $T : \Bbb R^3 → \Bbb R^3$ given by rotation around the direction $(1, 1, 1)$ by $\pi/2$ radians counter-clockwise (according to the right hand rule).

Find the matrix $A$ representing $T$.

Got no idea how to start this problem. Can someone give me a starting point?

Comment: Find an orthonormal basis in which the matrix has a simple form. Probably one of its vectors will be a normalized $(1,1,1)$ which will be mapped to itself, and the two other vectors $v,w$ will be orthogonal to it, being mapped to $w,-v$.

Answer (score 1):

[Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) states if $\;\vec v\;$ is rotated about unit vector $\;\vec k\;$ through an angle $\;\theta\;$ anticlockwise the rotated vector becomes
$$
\vec v_{\text{rot}}=\vec v\cos\theta+(\vec k\times\vec v)\sin\theta+\vec k\cdot(\vec k\cdot\vec v)(1-\cos\theta)
$$
In our case $$\vec k={1\over\sqrt 3}(1,1,1)^\top,\quad\theta={\pi\over2}$$
If $R$ is the coveted matrix,
$$R\vec v=\vec v_{\text{rot}}$$
Taking $\;\vec v=(1,0,0)^\top$ we get
$$
R\vec v=\text{1st column of }R=(\vec k\times\vec v)+\vec k\cdot(\vec k\cdot\vec v)=\frac{1}{3}(1,1+\sqrt3,1-\sqrt3)^\top
$$
Similarly other columns of $R$ can be computed. In fact,
$$
R=\frac{1}{3}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1-\sqrt3 & 1+\sqrt3\\
1+\sqrt3 & 1 & 1-\sqrt3\\
1-\sqrt3 & 1+\sqrt3 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much ! This is actually my first time asking questions on Stack Exchange. Never thought the answer would be explained so clearly!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

Consider the following **direct** orthonormal basis:

$$U=\pmatrix{b\\b\\b},V=\pmatrix{ \ 0\\ \ a\\-a}, W=U \times V=\pmatrix{-2c\\ \ c\\ \ c}$$

with $a:=1/\sqrt{2}, b:=1/\sqrt{3}, c:=ab=1/\sqrt{6}.$

The rotation matrix $R$ we are looking for is a direct (counterclockwise)  $\pi/2$ rotation leaving  $U$ fixed,

Thus $RU=U, \ \ RV=W, \ \ RW=-U,$ the last two equations expressing that the restriction of $R$ to the plane orthogonal to $U$ is a "pure $\pi/2$ 2D" rotation.

The 3 preceeding relationships can be gathered into a single one, which is:

$$R.[U,V,W]=[U,W,-V].$$

Consequently:

$R=[U,W,-V].[U,V,W]^{-1}=[U,W,-V].[U,V,W]^{T}$ (because $[U,V,W]$ is an orthogonal matrix).

giving, with the help of Mathematica:

$$R=\frac{1}{3}\pmatrix{1&1-\sqrt{3}&1+\sqrt{3}\\1+\sqrt{3}&1&1-\sqrt{3}\\1-\sqrt{3}&1+\sqrt{3}&1}.$$

which is the same as the solution of Jack's wasted life.

Comment: Thank you! This is actually my first time asking questions on Stack Exchange. Never thought the answer would be explained so clearly!